# Display PDF in a Form in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

When i use AxAcroPDF1 in VB.net to open a PDF inside a form it gives me an error. 
This only happens on Windows 7 64 bit. I have been told to compile as a x86 application but i cannot do that as i have several other DLL's in the program that are not 64 bit specific and so the build falis.

I have also tried using a browser in VB.net , it opens fine in XP, bit widows 7 it opens a new window and it's maximized and therefore the content behind get hidden

Any ideas on how to open the PDF inside a form in win xp and Win 7 , 32 bit and 64 bit ?

Comment: Not a new flash but PDF and Windows do not play well together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by just using the browser to open the PDF. browser1.navigate("path+filename")

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, and only fixed it by forcing every project in my solution to compile as 32-bit. I'd be very interested if there is a better way.

Comment: Ok that works if you are deploying to a 32 bit machine. I am already  deploying on 32 bit win7 with no issues, but on a 64 bit machine throws errors

Comment: When I say all projects, I really mean all projects. So every library, DLL project etc in your solution needs to be set to 32-bit compilation. Like I said, though, it's not a very good solution since your app becomes a 32-bit app run inside WOW64